# REPLACE to just have a number causing conversion failure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a count to see how many fields in column `value` are > 10:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.value > 10)
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
    END
FROM table t
WHERE t.DATE = '2017-01-01'
```

However, the column has a few custom entries like `+15` or `>14.0`, so I added the following:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN value LIKE '>%'
            and Replace(value, '>', '')  > 10)
FROM table t
WHERE t.DATE = '2017-01-01'
```

However, after doing that, I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '>14.0' to data
>   type int. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other
>   SET operation.

Seeing I have no access to rewrite the database with an `UPDATE`, does anyone have a workaround solution?

Comment: Can you put a CAST or CONVERT around the CASE statement?

Comment: You should close your count after the END

Comment: Please include the full SQL statement, or at least enough to evaluate it. You don't even have the full `CASE` statement in your second example, so it's impossible to know what's going on for certain.

Comment: @MJH yes, it turned out I needed 2 other `CAST` uses

Comment: @TomH, thanks - will make sure to include full SQL statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the table and sample data, but it sounds like you have strings that are numbers and a sign.

You can cast it to convert the data since you are mixing and matching data types.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(value AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE '>%'
            and CAST(Replace(value, '>', '') AS your_num_datatype_here)  > 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

You *could* fix this, either by simply changing `10` to `10.0`:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN '14.0' > 10.0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This will cause the implicit conversion of `'14.0'` to decimal rather than int, which works, or you explicitly convert it:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(14, 2), '14.0') > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

If it were me however, and I was not in a position to update the data, and do something a bit left field, like [use a numeric data type to store numbers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type), I would ignore these values completely, and simply use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) to avoid the conversion errors:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(14, 2), value) > 10 THEN 1 END)
```

It is a varchar column, so the possibilities of what nonsense could be in there are endless, you might get a query that works now by replacing `>` and `+`, but then what about when someone puts in `<`, or ends up with a space in between like `+ 14`, or something completely random like `'aaaa'`, where does it end?